# Why don't electrons in a fission reaction run out due to chain reactions?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, atoms, nuclear-engineering

I was watching an explanation (found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrk7Mt2fx6Y)) on nuclear fission. In the video, she described the process of fission to happen one a random neutron smashes into a uranium nucleus. This causes the nucleus to split into krpyton and barium, taking part of the nucleon and electrons with it, along with a few extra neutrons. The extra neutrons then smash into other uranium nucleuses, causing the chain reaction.

My question is, if you start with only $x$ electrons in the original uranium atom, you must run out of electrons soon in the chain reaction. Where do the extra electrons, needed to continue the chain reaction, come from?

Comment: The electrons don't really play a part in the (neutron+Uranium) fission reaction and the total number of electrons remains unchanged. Are you sure  you didn't mean to ask something else?

Answer (score 3):

A possible fission reaction equation is as follows:

$$^{235}_ {\;92}\rm U +_0^1n\rightarrow ^{236}_ {\;92}U\rightarrow ^{140}_ {\;54}Xe+ ^{94}_ {38}Sr+2_0^1n$$

This equation is balanced if neutral atoms are produced.
Even if ions were produced there would still balance of positive and negative charges.

$\rm ^{140}_ {\;54}Xe$ and $\rm ^{94}_ {38}Sr$ are radioactive because they are neutron rich and undergo beta decays which converts neutrons into protons in the nucleus with the emission of fast moving electrons (beta particles).

$\rm ^{140}_ {\;54}Xe$ undergoes four beta decays and ends up as $\rm ^{140}_ {\;58}Ce^{4+}$ and four electrons have been emitted.
Eventually the $\rm ^{140}_ {\;54}Xe^{4+}$ finds four electrons (or the intermediate products collect electrons) and a neutral atom is produced.
Similarly the  $\rm ^{94}_ {38}Sr$ undergoes two beta decays, collects two electrons and forms an atom of $\rm ^{94}_ {40}Zr$

Answer (score 2):

The electrons balance the number of protons in matter, and the total charge is zero, and there is the [law of conservation of charge.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation)

Protons and electrons do not decay . There can be no running out of electrons (or protons) except temporarily , until the new nuclei gather by electromagnetic  attraction the necessary electrons for the new nuclei to become neutral.

Comment: is the only way to destroy an electron through annihilation with a positron?

Comment: the annihilation diagram could be virtual ; in nuclear reactions,through the weak interaction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture  also http://www.cyberphysics.co.uk/topics/particle/feynman.htm